# To find the memory usage of a particular process

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, memory

I am developing an application in visual basic 2010, that finds the memory usage of a particular process. I came across this code:

```
        Option Explicit

Private Sub Command1_Click()
    Debug.Print GetProcessMemory("vb6.exe")
End Sub

Private Function GetProcessMemory(ByVal app_name As String) As String
    Dim Process As Object
    Dim dMemory As Double
    For Each Process In GetObject("winmgmts:").ExecQuery("Select WorkingSetSize from Win32_Process Where Name = '" & app_name & "'")
        dMemory = Process.WorkingSetSize
    Next
    If dMemory > 0 Then
        GetProcessMemory = ResizeKb(dMemory)
    Else
        GetProcessMemory = "0 Bytes"
    End If
End Function

Private Function ResizeKb(ByVal b As Double) As String
    Dim bSize(8) As String, i As Integer
    bSize(0) = "Bytes"
    bSize(1) = "KB" 'Kilobytes
    bSize(2) = "MB" 'Megabytes
    bSize(3) = "GB" 'Gigabytes
    bSize(4) = "TB" 'Terabytes
    bSize(5) = "PB" 'Petabytes
    bSize(6) = "EB" 'Exabytes
    bSize(7) = "ZB" 'Zettabytes
    bSize(8) = "YB" 'Yottabytes
    For i = UBound(bSize) To 0 Step -1
        If b >= (1024 ^ i) Then
            ResizeKb = ThreeNonZeroDigits(b / (1024 ^ _
                i)) & " " & bSize(i)
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
End Function

Private Function ThreeNonZeroDigits(ByVal value As Double) As Double
    If value >= 100 Then
        ThreeNonZeroDigits = FormatNumber(value)
    ElseIf value >= 10 Then
        ThreeNonZeroDigits = FormatNumber(value, 1)
    Else
        ThreeNonZeroDigits = FormatNumber(value, 2)
    End If
End Function
```

but this does not work in vb2010. It returns 0bytes. Please help. Alternative techniques are also appreciated.

Comment: How exactly are you calling `GetProcessMemory`? When you step through it in the debugger, does it actually execute anything in the `for each` loop? What have you tried to do to debug this yourself? There's nothing there that should matter whether it's run in `vb2010` or another version of vb.net. Also, please don't put tag information in your title. The tagging system here is very good at classifying things, and doesn't need help. :-) Please see [Should questions include "tags" in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19190/172661). Thanks.

Comment: @KenWhite I am passing the name of the process as input to GetProcessMemory.

Comment: Well, that's one third of the questions I asked you. :-) How about the other two?

Comment: @KenWhite No it doesn't. I tried to display the value of dMemory on a listbox, just after the line dMemory = Process.WorkingSetSize ,but it did not show any result. i found this code somewhere on a blog, so i actually did not do any modification.

Comment: "No, it doesn't" what? Execute the line inside the `for each` loop? Then you've provided the wrong process name or lack sufficient user privileges to run the management query. If that line of code never executes, `dMemory` will *always* be zero. To see if that line executes, **set a debugger breakpoint** and step through the code to see if it executes. Examining `dMemory` tells you absolutely nothing if you don't know if the query ever ran in the first place.

Comment: @KenWhite Sir thanks for the advice, but i gave the right process name, and that too from the task manager. Does it have to do anything with the operating system? I am using windows7 :-)

Comment: For the last time: Did you step through it in the debugger? You're reading about half of what I'm writing every time, and it's getting a little annoying wasting time here if you're going to ignore what I'm writing. **Use the debugger.** If you're not willing to do that, I'm going to vote to close this question because you're not being cooperative.

Comment: @KenWhite I'm sorry for the inconvenience. Yes, this time i did use a breakpoint as you said. The query did not execute in the first place.

Comment: Then as I've explained already, you either don't have sufficient privileges to run it, or you're using the wrong process name and it's not finding results. The loop can only run if the query succeeds and at least one process is  returned.

Comment: Apart from this, is there any other way how i can obtain the memory usage of a particular process?