# Excel VBA error: "cannot complete task with available resources"

Tags: excel, vba

I wonder whether someone may be able to help me please.

With some help along the way I've put together the following script which performs the following:

- Searches column **B** (containing approx 31,000 rows of data) of the sheet **"All Data"** for unique values.
- For each unique value, the code will then try to find a matching sheet with the same value within my workbook.
- Where a match is found I'm then trying to use the code below to create a graph from data on that sheet.

```
Sub ForecastsCharts()

    Dim ChtOb As ChartObject
    Dim lw As Long
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim RngToCover As Range
    Dim sShapeName As String
    Dim shtrng As Range
    Dim i As Long
    Dim RowIndex
    Dim ad As Worksheet
    Dim col As Long
    Dim DataRow As Long
    Dim rw As Long

    Sheets("All Data").Select
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    DataRow = 8

    Do Until Cells(DataRow, 2).Value = "" ' Loop through All Data rows
        With Sheets(Cells(DataRow, 2).Value) ' Output will go to the applicable Portfolio sheet found in column B

            Set rng = .Range("B11").CurrentRegion

            'If Application.CountIf(rng, "<>") = rng.Columns.Count Then   ' all data points required

            If Application.CountIf(rng, "<>") > 0 Then    ' at least 1 data point
                With ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart(Left:=48, Width:=468, Top:=300, Height:=300).Chart
                    .PlotBy = xlRows
                    .ChartType = xlColumnClustered
                    For RowIndex = 2 To rng.Rows.Count
                        With .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
                            'This is the series name
                            .Name = "='" & rng.Parent.Name & "'!" & rng.Cells(RowIndex, 1).Address(, , xlR1C1)
                            .Values = "='" & rng.Parent.Name & "'!" & rng.Rows(RowIndex).Cells(1, 2).Resize(1, rng.Columns.Count - 1).Address(, , xlR1C1)
                            .XValues = "='" & rng.Parent.Name & "'!" & rng.Rows(1).Cells(1, 2).Resize(1, rng.Columns.Count - 1).Address(, , xlR1C1)
                            .ApplyDataLabels AutoText:=True, LegendKey:=False, _
                            HasLeaderLines:=True, ShowSeriesName:=False, _
                            ShowCategoryName:=False, ShowValue:=True, _
                            ShowPercentage:=True, ShowBubbleSize:=False, _
                            Separator:="" & Chr(13) & ""
                        End With
                    Next
                End With
            End If
        End With
    Loop
End Sub
```

**UPDATED CODE**

```
Sub ForecastsCharts()

    Dim ChtOb As ChartObject
    Dim lw As Long
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim RngToCover As Range
    Dim sShapeName As String
    Dim shtrng As Range
    Dim i As Long
    Dim RowIndex As Long
    Dim ad As Worksheet
    Dim col As Long
    Dim DataRow As Long
    Dim rw As Long
    Dim allDataSheet As Worksheet


    Set allDataSheet = Sheets("All Data")
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    DataRow = 8

    Do Until allDataSheet.Cells(DataRow, 2).Value = "" ' Loop through All Data rows
        With Sheets(allDataSheet.Cells(DataRow, 2).Value) ' Output will go to the applicable Portfolio sheet found in column B

    Set rng = .Range("B8").CurrentRegion

    'If Application.CountIf(rng, "<>") = rng.Columns.Count Then   ' all data points required

    If Application.CountIf(rng, "<>") > 0 Then    ' at least 1 data point
        With .Shapes.AddChart(Left:=48, Width:=468, Top:=300, Height:=300).Chart
            .PlotBy = xlRows
            .ChartType = xlColumnClustered
            For RowIndex = 2 To rng.Rows.Count
                With .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
                    'This is the series name
                    .Name = "='" & rng.Parent.Name & "'!" & rng.Cells(RowIndex, 1).Address(, , xlR1C1)
                    .Values = "='" & rng.Parent.Name & "'!" & rng.Rows(RowIndex).Cells(1, 2).Resize(1, rng.Columns.Count - 1).Address(, , xlR1C1)
                    .XValues = "='" & rng.Parent.Name & "'!" & rng.Rows(1).Cells(1, 2).Resize(1, rng.Columns.Count - 1).Address(, , xlR1C1)
                    .ApplyDataLabels AutoText:=True, LegendKey:=False, _
                        HasLeaderLines:=True, ShowSeriesName:=False, _
                        ShowCategoryName:=False, ShowValue:=True, _
                        ShowPercentage:=True, ShowBubbleSize:=False, _
                        Separator:="" & Chr(13) & ""
                End With
            Next
        End With
    End If
    End With
    DataRow = DataRow + 1
    Loop
    End Sub
```

*****WORKING CODE*****

```
Sub ForecastsCharts()

        Dim ChtOb As ChartObject
        Dim lw As Long
        Dim rng As Range
        Dim RngToCover As Range
        Dim sShapeName As String
        Dim shtrng As Range
        Dim i As Long
        Dim RowIndex As Long
        Dim ad As Worksheet
        Dim col As Long
        Dim DataRow As Long
        Dim rw As Long
        Dim bottomB As Integer
        Dim ws As Worksheet

        Application.ScreenUpdating = False

        Set ad = Sheets("Portfolio List")

        ad.Select

        bottomB = Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        For Each rng In ad.Range("C8:C" & bottomB)
            If rng > 0 Then
                Set ws = Sheets(rng.Value)

                Set shtrng = ws.Range("B8").CurrentRegion

                'If Application.CountIf(rng, "<>") = rng.Columns.Count Then   ' all data points required
                With ws
                    If ws.Name = "Benefits & Credits" Then
                        If Application.CountIf(shtrng, "<>") > 0 Then    ' at least 1 data point
                            With .Shapes.AddChart(Left:=48, Width:=468, Top:=300, Height:=300).Chart
                                .PlotBy = xlRows
                                .ChartType = xlColumnClustered
                                For RowIndex = 2 To shtrng.Rows.Count
                                    With .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
                                        'This is the series name
                                        .Name = "='" & shtrng.Parent.Name & "'!" & shtrng.Cells(RowIndex, 1).Address(, , xlR1C1)
                                        .Values = "='" & shtrng.Parent.Name & "'!" & shtrng.Rows(RowIndex).Cells(1, 2).Resize(1, shtrng.Columns.Count - 1).Address(, , xlR1C1)
                                        .XValues = "='" & shtrng.Parent.Name & "'!" & shtrng.Rows(1).Cells(1, 2).Resize(1, shtrng.Columns.Count - 1).Address(, , xlR1C1)
                                        .ApplyDataLabels AutoText:=True, LegendKey:=False, _
                                        HasLeaderLines:=True, ShowSeriesName:=False, _
                                        ShowCategoryName:=False, ShowValue:=True, _
                                        ShowPercentage:=True, ShowBubbleSize:=False, _
                                        Separator:="" & Chr(13) & ""
                                    End With
                                Next
                            End With
                        End If
                    End If
                End With
            End If
        Next rng
    End Sub
```

I know that the code to create the graph works, because I've tested this with a single sheet. I also know that the following part of the script which identifies the unique values to match to a sheet name also works because I use this in a another script.

```
DataRow = 8

        Do Until Cells(DataRow, 2).Value = "" ' Loop through All Data rows
            With Sheets(Cells(DataRow, 2).Value) ' Output will go to the applicable Portfolio sheet found in column B
```

But the problem I have when I run the complete script is that Excel crashes creating a "Excel cannot complete this task with available resources. Choose less data or close other applications" error message and I've no idea why because my pc is powerful enough to run this.

I have looked at similar posts on this forum, but unfortunately they've not been able to shed any light on the problem.

I just wondered whether someone could possibly look at this please and let me know where I'm going wrong

Comment: Am I reading this wrong, or are you trying to add 31K charts?  Excel files have a size limit, and you could be exceeding that.  Try adding a breakpoint in so that you can see if you make it through the loop.

Comment: Hi Degustaf, thank you for taking the time to read my post and come back to me about this. No there are 31,000 rows of data which the macro searches for unique values in column B from. In reality there are 12 unique values, creating twelve sheets which I'm trying to create a chart on. Kind Regards

Comment: Have you tried getting rid of the Sheets("All Data").Select line? Perhaps instead of doing that, create a Worksheet object. Dim allDataSheet as Worksheet and then in the next line Set allDataSheet = Sheets("All Data"). Then where you have objects like Cells replace them with allDataSheet.Cells. Most memory issues I've run into are somehow related to using "Select"

Comment: Hi @DeanBDean, thank you very much for coming back to me with this. I've inserted the suggested fix, and although the code definitely runs further,unfortunately I'm receiving a error on this line `.Name = "='" & rng.Parent.Name & "'!" & rng.Cells(RowIndex, 1).Address(, , xlR1C1)`, which following your suggestion now reads `.Name = "='" & rng.Parent.Name & "'!" & rng.allDataSheetCells(RowIndex, 1).Address(, , xlR1C1)`. The error is "Object doesn't support this property or method. Many thanks and kind regards.

Comment: I believe I led you a bit astray by not being clear. I don't believe you need to change that line at all. With my suggestion, after creating the allDataSheet Worksheet Object, I am pretty sure you would only need to modify the code in three place. The two references to `Cells(DataRow, 2).Value` would change to `allDataSheet.Cells(DataRow, 2).Value` and I am pretty sure you can delete the reference to the ActiveSheet. So `ActiveSheet.Shapes...` should become `.Shapes...`

Comment: Hi @DeanBDean, thank you for coming back to me with this. I've amended my code as shown above and as per your recommendations, but unfortunately I'm back to the original error message. I've tested this on a smaller file where the "All Data" sheet has approx 50 rows and it works fine, but doesn't when I come to the larger file. Many thanks and kind regards

Comment: Really sorry to hear that. The next thing I'd suggest you'd try is to see how many loops before this fails. Right after the loop starts have a line that puts the DataRow - 7 into a cell. Run it a couple times and see if its failing on exactly the same loop or if it is varying. If it is varying, then it will probably be a difficult issue to track down. If it is failing on the same loop each time, you might be able to track down exactly which line its failing on.

Comment: Also, do you want a bunch of graphs with single series, or one graph with a lot of series?  It looks like you're adding a new graph at each iteration..not just a new series.  Also, you can only have 255 series per chart.  So I think you may have to rethink your strategy.

Comment: As already mentioned, it seems you are re-creating the graph with each iteration, might a suggest a compromise?  You should scan the values and append them to a single sheet with specified columns for each of your 12 unique values, once all values have been analyzed and appended to the appropriate ranges, run your graph making code ONCE on each range, it may require two steps but it should run properly.

Comment: Check this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17202892/to-find-the-memory-usage-of-a-particular-process to see how you could add some logging of how your excel uses memory. You might be able to draw some conclusions out of that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I understood your goal as: single chart per sheet that exists in the *All Data* list

Your code was creating (as @vba4all suggested) too many charts. I added:

1. `sheetsHandled as Collection` to hold the list of sheets that
   already got their charts.
2. `sheetName` to hold the name of the sheet used many times in code.
3. `Function StringExistsInCollection` that looks for the `sheetName`
   in `sheetsHandled`.

So here is the fixed code:

```
Sub ForecastsCharts()

    Dim ChtOb As ChartObject
    Dim lw As Long
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim RngToCover As Range
    Dim sShapeName As String
    Dim shtrng As Range
    Dim i As Long
    Dim RowIndex As Long
    Dim ad As Worksheet
    Dim col As Long
    Dim DataRow As Long
    Dim rw As Long
    Dim allDataSheet As Worksheet

    Dim sheetsHandled As New Collection 'Collection for chart references
    Dim sheetName As String ' Name of the sheet being handled (used many times)

    Set allDataSheet = Sheets("All Data")
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    DataRow = 8

    Do Until allDataSheet.Cells(DataRow, 2).Value = "" ' Loop through All Data rows

    sheetName = allDataSheet.Cells(DataRow, 2).Value 'Name is memorised here

    If Not StringExistsInCollection(sheetsHandled, sheetName) Then

        sheetsHandled.Add sheetName 'Remember we handled the sheet

        With Sheets(sheetName) ' Output will go to the applicable Portfolio sheet found in column B

        Set rng = .Range("B8").CurrentRegion

        'If Application.CountIf(rng, "<>") = rng.Columns.Count Then   ' All data points required

        If Application.CountIf(rng, "<>") > 0 Then    ' At least one data point

            With .Shapes.AddChart(Left:=48, Width:=468, Top:=300, Height:=300).Chart
                .PlotBy = xlRows
                .ChartType = xlColumnClustered
                For RowIndex = 2 To rng.Rows.Count
                    With .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
                        'This is the series name
                        .Name = "='" & sheetName & "'!" & rng.Cells(RowIndex, 1).Address(, , xlR1C1)
                        .Values = "='" & sheetName & "'!" & rng.Rows(RowIndex).Cells(1, 2).Resize(1, rng.Columns.Count - 1).Address(, , xlR1C1)
                        .XValues = "='" & sheetName & "'!" & rng.Rows(1).Cells(1, 2).Resize(1, rng.Columns.Count - 1).Address(, , xlR1C1)
                        .ApplyDataLabels AutoText:=True, LegendKey:=False, _
                            HasLeaderLines:=True, ShowSeriesName:=False, _
                            ShowCategoryName:=False, ShowValue:=True, _
                            ShowPercentage:=True, ShowBubbleSize:=False, _
                            Separator:="" & Chr(13) & ""
                    End With
                Next
            End With
        End If
        End With
    End If 'End to if not sheet is handled
    DataRow = DataRow + 1
    Loop

End Sub

Public Function StringExistsInCollection(ByRef aCollection As Collection, item As String) As Boolean
    StringExistsInCollection = False
    For i = 1 To aCollection.Count
        If aCollection(i) = item Then
            StringExistsInCollection = True
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next i
End Function
```

Comment: Hi @Grendler, thank you very much for taking the time to reply to my post and for the solution. I have tried this but unfortunately it doesn't quite work as expected. The charts are created on each page but the code does not loop through the data rows and plot the information in the chart. Many thanks and kind regards.

Comment: Hi @Grendler, over the last few days I've persevered with your code, because I felt that just must be something simple I was missing and there was. I stepped through the code and realised it was trying to use the page title as the starting point to applying the chart values. As soon as I added a header to B7, just above the start of the range, the code works perfectly. So I just wanted to let you know. Thank you very much for all your help. All the best and kind regards.

Answer (score 1):

You could benefit from a log-file outside of Excel to help you track what is happening. Here is a simplified function that I use a lot for tracking what is going on. It is writing the text you provide to the function into a text-file, so even when excel crashes, you still have the log. 
You could combine it with the GetProcessMemory function found in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17202892/to-find-the-memory-usage-of-a-particular-process)

```
Option Explicit

Sub Heartbeat(LogText As String)
'-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
'Purpose    Enable logging where the program is
'Expects    LogText The freetext log that describes what is being logged.
'-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
'Usage      Heartbeat "this text will end up in the text-file"
'           Heartbeat GetProcessMemory("EXCEL.EXE")     'requires the GetProcessMemory function
'                                                        https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17202892/to-find-the-memory-usage-of-a-particular-process  
'-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
'-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
'Changelog
'HANY 20140416
'   Created
'-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

Dim fname As String
Dim myLogText As String
Dim myfilenumber As Integer


'If there are any ' or " in the log-text, take them away.
myLogText = Replace(LogText, "'", "*")
myLogText = Replace(myLogText, """", "*")

'----------------------------------------------------
'Log in the text-file
'----------------------------------------------------
fname = "Mylogfile.log.txt"
myfilenumber = FreeFile
Open fname For Append As #myfilenumber
Print #myfilenumber, FormatLogTime(Now()) & "--" & LogText
Close #myfilenumber

End Sub

Function FormatLogTime(iDate As Date) As String
FormatLogTime = Right("0000" & Year(iDate), 4) _
              & Right("00" & Month(iDate), 2) _
              & Right("00" & Day(iDate), 2) _
              & " " _
              & Right("00" & Hour(iDate), 2) _
              & "." _
              & Right("00" & Minute(iDate), 2) _
              & "." _
              & Right("00" & Second(iDate), 2)

End Function
```

Comment: Hi @Nybbe, thank you for taking the time to respond to my post with the above code. I'm not sure you will see from the post I made a couple of days ago but I've got around the problem with the system 'Resources'. Admittedly, I have a few issues, but these would go off topic from the original post, so I'm not sure I need to implement your 'log code'. Kind Regards

Comment: Good to hear that you are on track to solve your problems. I found one bug in my logging-code that I just corrected.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...  it makes use of arrays 3 to be precise I tested with everything but creating the charts.  I had roughly 1 thousand rows of numbers and approximately 6 sheets it found the matches in a matter of seconds.  Iterating with array is much less memory intensive than iterating through cells...

```
Option Explicit
Sub ForecastsCharts()

        Dim ChtOb As ChartObject
        Dim lw As Long
        Dim rng As Range
        Dim RngToCover As Range
        Dim sShapeName As String
        Dim shtrng As Range
        Dim i As Long
        Dim RowIndex As Long
        Dim ad As Worksheet
        Dim ws As Worksheet
        Dim col As Long
        Dim DataRow As Long
        Dim rw As Long
        Dim PortListArr As Variant, p As Variant
        Dim SheetNameArr As Variant, s As Variant
        Dim wb As Workbook
        Dim MatchSheetArr() As Variant, m As Long

        Set wb = ThisWorkbook
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False

        Set ad = Sheets("Portfolio List")

       'get array of sheet Names
        ReDim SheetNameArr(0 To Sheets.Count - 1)
        For i = 0 To Sheets.Count - 1
            If wb.Sheets(i + 1).Name <> "Portfolio List" Then
                SheetNameArr(i) = wb.Sheets(i + 1).Name
            End If
        Next i

        'get arry of numbers
        PortListArr = ad.Range("C2", Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).Value
        m = 0

        'loop through each element of numbers and compare with each sheet name if match is found populate into new array
        For Each p In PortListArr
            For Each s In SheetNameArr
                If "Sheet" & p = s Then
                    ReDim Preserve MatchSheetArr(m)
                    MatchSheetArr(m) = s
                    Debug.Print MatchSheetArr(m)
                    m = m + 1
                End If
            Next s
        Next p

        Set SheetNameArr = Nothing
        Set PortListArr = Nothing
        Set p = Nothing

        For Each s In MatchSheetArr 'array of only matched sheet names
            Set ws = wb.Worksheets(s)
            Set shtrng = ws.Range("B8").CurrentRegion
            If Application.CountIf(shtrng, "<>") > 0 Then    ' at least 1 data point
                With ws.Shapes.AddChart(Left:=48, Width:=468, Top:=300, Height:=300).Chart
                    .PlotBy = xlRows
                    .ChartType = xlColumnClustered
                    For RowIndex = 2 To shtrng.Rows.Count
                        With .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
                            'This is the series name
                            .Name = "='" & shtrng.Parent.Name & "'!" & shtrng.Cells(RowIndex, 1).Address(, , xlR1C1)
                            .Values = "='" & shtrng.Parent.Name & "'!" & shtrng.Rows(RowIndex).Cells(1, 2).Resize(1, shtrng.Columns.Count - 1).Address(, , xlR1C1)
                            .XValues = "='" & shtrng.Parent.Name & "'!" & shtrng.Rows(1).Cells(1, 2).Resize(1, shtrng.Columns.Count - 1).Address(, , xlR1C1)
                            .ApplyDataLabels AutoText:=True, LegendKey:=False, _
                            HasLeaderLines:=True, ShowSeriesName:=False, _
                            ShowCategoryName:=False, ShowValue:=True, _
                            ShowPercentage:=True, ShowBubbleSize:=False, _
                            Separator:="" & Chr(13) & ""
                        End With
                    Next
                End With
            End If
        Next

        Set s = Nothing
        Set MatchSheetArr = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi @cplett, thank you very much for taking the time to reply to my post and for putting this together. Unfortunately I couldn't get this to work. When I ran the code, I received a "Cannot assign to array" error message, highlighting this line as the cause: `Set MatchSheetArr = Nothing`. I suspect it may because of this line `If wb.Sheets(i + 1).Name <> "Portfolio List" Then` which won't be the only sheet in the workbook, besides the destination sheets I'm trying to add the charts to, although I'm happy to be proven wrong. Kind Regards

Comment: IRHM the code creates an array of all sheets names NOT titled "Portfolio List" ... it then creates an array of the range of numbers located in column C of of the sheet titled "Portfolio List", it then iterates through both arrays examining every number against every sheet name and if it finds a match ...`If "Sheet" & p = s Then` it then populates that sheet name in to a new array of only the matches.  My thought was that you could then do what you wanted to with the array of matched sheets.  If this is not what you are going for I must have misread your post.

Comment: Hi @cplett, thank you for taking the time to come back to me with this. Your clear explanation does confirm my thinking around this. The problem with this is that the "Portfolio List" sheet isn't the sheet within the workbook, some of which I don't want to add a chart to, so when I ran the code which created the charts the code was trying to create a chart on all of the sheet within the workbook. Many thanks  and kind regards

Comment: @IRHM this is simple to address...  In the for loop that gets array of sheet names you can simply add more conditions to the if statement e.g.  `If wb.Sheets(i + 1).Name <> "Portfolio List" And wb.sheets(i+1).Name <> "Don't add this Sheet Name" And wb.Sheets(i+1) <> "Don't add this Sheet Name either Then` etc...

Answer (score -1):

Try adding this just above `Loop`:

```
DataRow = DataRow + 1
```

It's possible you aren't advancing through the range.  (This is easy to check while running the code with a breakpoint.)

Also after adding the line I suggest above, you might change:

```
Do Until Cells(DataRow, 2).Value = ""
```

to:

```
Do Until Cells(DataRow, 2).Value = "" Or DataRow > 12
```

The idea is to put an early stop on the resource-usage.  If the code works without raising the error, you will of course not have your needed result but you may be in better position to find the problem.

Comment: Hi @Smandoli thank you for taking the time to reply to my post and for the suggested fix. I've inserted the line but unfortunately I'm still faced with the same error. Many thanks and kind regards

Comment: I wonder how many charts you create while running this code.  Try new suggestion above to limit the number of loops.

Comment: Hi Smandoli, thank you for coming back to me so quickly with this. I tried the amended code you kindly posted and the code ran without error, but as you said the graphs weren't created. For information I'm creating 12 charts. Many thanks and kind regards.

Comment: Set `ScreenUpdating = True` in case that is hiding any issues, make sure `Option Explicit` is at the top of every module and the code compiles, and use this guide: http://www.cpearson.com/Excel/DebuggingVBA.aspx

Comment: Hi Samondoli, thank you for this I'll give it a try. Kind Regards

Comment: It's a pleasure, and well worth the unconstructive and anonymous down-vote.